# breezejs: pagination and lazy-loading

Tags: breeze

I'm retrieving MandatesHistory collection on the Mandate Entity like this:

```
  var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MandatesHistory")
                .where("Mandate.Id", "==", mandatId)
                .expand("Mandate").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);

            return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service));
```

It works great the first time and the collection is populated with 10 records (that's the value of pageSize).

But then the second time, the next 10 records are added to the collection instead of replacing the previous 10. So the collection keeps growing as I scroll through pages.

Obviously my pagination no longer works either, because it only expects 10 records per page, that is 10 records in the collection at any given time.

Is that expected behaviour ? If I specify skip and take, I'd rather that the collection gets overwritten after each query.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question. I'm not sure what 'collection' you are referring to, but I think part of the issue is a misunderstanding about the results of a query vs the contents of the EntityManager's cache.  When you execute a query with skip and take, the results returned by the query, typically in the *then*... method, will in fact be what you want. i.e. in your case exactly 10 records. ( assuming a pageSize of 10).

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MandatesHistory")
            .where("Mandate.Id", "==", mandatId)
            .expand("Mandate").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);


manager.executeQuery(query.using(service)).then(data) {
   var next10items = data.results; // this will always be 10 ( or less) records.
});
```

The EntityManager's cache on the other hand will grow with each 'new' page of data that it sees. But in general you shouldn't care about this. You should just be working with the results of the query each time.

Does this make sense?

Comment: The issue is that I've bound to my View (using angularjs) a collection property of my entity through which I loop to display the records in a paginated table. However, I only want to display the ten records returned by the query, according to which page I'm on. Maybe I should bind to the results directly instead of the entity's property. That way I would avoid the cache issue, but I find it pretty inconvenient. Is this clearer  ?

Comment: Sorry, not really :)  If you created the collection and only want to bind to 10 records within it, then just clear the collection before filling it with the results of your query.  I think I must be missing something.

Comment: The way I fill in the collection does not allow me to clear beforehand. I use Expand and I let breeze merging the collection with the existing entity (in cache)

Comment: I'm pretty sure we (Jay and I) are not sure which collection you are binding too ... and how. Perhaps we can attack this if you work backward from the Ng binding to the collection and from there back to how you set that collection.